# version control- merge two branches - [abort: uncommitted changes]

Tags: python, django, mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

I have two branches. `default` and `dev`.

`default` is the main, `dev` is development branch. Now i did something in dev and committed and pushed to dev with tortoisehg.

Now I want to merge dev into default. what I did:

```
hg update default
hg merge dev.
```

but I am getting this:
`abort: outstanding uncommitted changes (use 'hg status' to list changes)`.

what should I do to get the dev changeset into default?

please help.

Comment: Seems that somewhere you have changes that has been uncommitted. Most likely in `default` branch

Comment: @PauloBu, no not in default. in dev as i said above. how do i merge them together?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707962/how-to-merge-two-branches-in-mercurial-when-there-is-nothing-to-merge

Answer (score 3):

Commit.  It's telling you that.  `hg merge` is an operation that includes the working directory, and if your working directory has uncommitted changes you're asking Mercurial to start a process that you couldn't safely cancel.

Comment: how can i commit? it is asking for username :(

Comment: I recommend that you look at this site for a lesson on Mercurial: [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/index.html).  About half way down chapter 2 it has a section titled "Setting up a username".

Comment: "Finally someone is here to help?"  You had an answer within an hour.  Google "asynchronous".

Comment: In my case, I get the same error. 
Running hg status in dev branch however shows no changes. When I try to commit in dev again it says no changes. 
So, I am guessing default branch had some changes? If so without going to default branch with hg update default, how do I commit changes in that?